# Computercraft lua change value later

Tags: lua, computercraft

ok, Im almost completely new to lua and computercraft but I have alot of creativity. I'm trying to write code that will reprint a variable every second. here is what I have so far:

```
display = "Loading..."
While true do
 sleep(1)
 term.clear()
 term.setCursorPos(1,1)
 print (display)
end
sleep(3)
display = "hello"
```

I want to use it to render a 2d game, the "display" variable would change often and thus why i want it to be updated every second.

It does indeed refresh every second when I run the code but for some reason I cant seem to get the "display" variable to change after 3 seconds to test it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly related to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926440/asynchronous-delay-in-lua-like-javascript-settimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not experienced in Lua, but this might be a solution: [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6684801/3163075)

> In the UI thread, run:
>
> ```
> while ((status=lua_resume(L_coroutine, 0)) == LUA_YIELD) {
>   semaphore_wait(); /* whatever the appropriate C# call is */
> }
> ```
>
> "Wait for response" should look something like:
>
> ```
> while not results[my_result] do
>   coroutine.yield()
> end
> ```
>
> The "incoming message" function should look like the following in Lua:
>
> ```
> results[cur_result]=parsed_message
> ```

Comment: I think it should be a comment

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz a comment doesn't provide the space to explain an answer to this depth. But yeah it's not a standard answer, but might be just what the OP needs in order to solve his problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but at the current point that i'm at, the post you linked to is a bit over my head. I will still mark it as correct as it may help other viewers that are more experienced than I am.

Comment: @ryzehalberd the most important thing is to change the `while true` to `while variable` that variable should return `false` at some point in the loop, so that the while can stop and code will move to the `sleep(3)` after the `end` of the while.

Answer (score 1):

`while true` is an infinite loop. The script never reaches `sleep(3)`.

Perhaps you want to replace `while true` with `for i=1,3`.

Comment: The problem with that Is that I want the loop to run the whole time, eventually I want to use it to render a 2d game, the "display" variable would change often and thus why i want it to be updated every second.